# Intercepting Date objects coming from BlazeDS and adjusting for timezone differences

Tags: java, apache-flex, date, timezone, blazeds

I am working on an application that is near the end of its development cycle and has mostly passed user testing. We recently realized that having flex convert dates to the client's local timezone is not desired, as all of our dates are in EST and contain no time data. Since BlazeDS sends dates in UTC, this results in the dates being converted to the day before in timezones west of EST.

The best solution is to go in and refactor all dates to adjust for the timezone offset, but that is just not doable at this stage. Since all dates in our application don't care about time, I would really like to be able to intercept all Date objects that come across BlazeDS and adjust for the timezone offset. Is it possible to do this? If not, are there any "cross cutting" solutions?

Thanks

Comment: I'm going to simply add a comment, since the following noise is probably more of an annoyance than a decent answer:  When working with the backend on the project I work on, there is a phrase I say every week, "EVERYTHING is a String."  I've answered similar questions on this random-ass site similarly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400178/flex-null-integer/2403726#2403726

Comment: As for an abstracted solution -- good luck.  The issue with the DateObject is, you cannot know, 100% without a data item attached to your response, what the server time is without a lot of front end code.

"cross-cutting":  find a way to have the backend return all dates as strings, and have your internal components that do anyting with dates NOT return date objects.... life will be much easier for you.

Comment: The function of converting the dates to EST is not the problem. That's easy to do with the `timezoneOffset` property and adjusting for EST. Either way, using Strings is not an option right now. We do date arithmetic and have sorting based on dates. Also, the application isn't small, so any fundamental change would require a lot of refactoring and unless that becomes the ONLY answer, it's not going to happen. (Not my choice.) I've been looking into extending the default `TypeHandler` to make the adjustments to the Date objects when they are deserialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform//reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/remoting/RemoteObject.html#convertResultHandler

You can inspect all the results from a RO call before they get passed to handlers.

I'm not sure that its a better way... as you'll be inspecting every message that comes back!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We decided to do something similar, but farther down the stack. We're going to default the time on all Dates that are pulled out of the database to be noon, to allow enough buffer for Flex to as it pleases. It's not ideal, but should work fine. Also, it's definitely good to have your answer in my back pocket to save the day another time. Thanks!