# Should I use DTOs or domain objects in flex when connecting to blazeds/java/jpa using remote-services?

Tags: apache-flex, jpa, remoting, blazeds, dto

I am working on an Adobe Flex front-end with a Java back-end using JPA for persistence. The protocol I am using is remote objects (AMF) implemented with BlazeDS.

I started out with a service-facade and entity DAOs, but without any specific DTOs. The same POJOs, the domain objects, were passed in the service-facade as those used as DTOs passed to the Hibernate DAOs.

However, the latest few days I have been thinking whether this is a good approach or not. The latest article on the subject I read was this one:
[Interesting JPA Pattern blog](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/05/jpa-implementation-patterns-service-facades-and-data-transfers-objects/)

**The situation:**
Say I have POJO `Book` with a unidirection `ManyToOne` relation with the POJO `Category` (i.e. each book may only be associated with one category, but the same category may be associated with many books). I see some alternatives:

**Alternative 1:**
I expose a method/operation `addUpdateBook(Book book)`. In the implementation of this operation I add/update both the book and the referenced category. I mean, if the client submits a book having a category that doesn't exist from before, this would mean that the client implicitly may edit categories using the addUpdateBook operation.

- the client is working directly with the domain model!
- the entire category information will be sent when a new book is added
  even though a reference to the category would be sufficient

**Alternative 2:**
I expose a method/operation `addUpdateBook(Book book,Long categoryId)`. In the implementation I retrieve the category for the given `categoryId` and replace the category given in the book POJO and then I persist the book. In other words, I ignore any category in the book object, I just look at the `categoryId`. This means that the client would need to use another operation in order to modify the category.

- pro: the client can still work more or less on the domain model, but ...
- con: ... it is confusing for the client that the category of the book
  object will be ignored
- con: the entire category information of the book will be sent, even
  if the server never will read it
- pro: it may be more clear when a separate operation should be used
  for category modifications
- con: I need to retrieve the category before persisting the book. I
  guess this means some overhead.

**Alternative 3:**
I expose a method/operation `addUpdateBook(BookDTO bookDto)`. The POJO `BookDTO` looks as the POJO `Book`, but instead of a field `Category category` it has a field `Long categoryId`. In the implementation I retrieve the `Category` for the given `categoryId` before I persist the `Book`.

- pro: not confusing for the client
- con(?): what should the method `getBook(Long bookId)` return? should it
  return only the `BookDTO`? Then it would be required to invoke also the
  operation `getCategory(Long categoryId)` in order to have "the entire
  book information". Then the client would need to set together the
  different parts to a local domain representation of the book.
  Compared to alternative 1 this would be more complex on the client
  side?
- con: I need to retrieve the category before persisting the book. I
  guess this means some overhead.
- con: being forced to use the DTOs in the client makes it deal with physical details thereby and makes it somewhat distant from the actual domain model. It seems like I am missing the point with having an domain model and using JPA in the business layer.

I guess (!) alternative 3 is the way you would design the operations in a SOA context. However, for me, it is not that important to be loosely-coupled between the client and server. My focus is not to provide multiple client-platform support.

**Which alternative would you propose? Are there other better alternatives?** Do you know any nice resources, such as code examples, which could help me?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using something related to "Alternative 3". In the beginning I've started to use domain objects (probably also because of my experience with [dataservices](http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/8.2/programLC/programmer/lcds/Part_Data_Management_1.html)), after a while I found too many problems and I've switched to DTO's. All the publing services are exposing only DTO's (both for input/output parameters).

Some of the problems that I've met during working directly with the domain objects and BlazeDS:

a)you need to break the domain objects encapsulation (like exposing properties, or exposing private constructors) in order to use them for data transfer. Otherwise you will have to write your own serialization/deserialization.

b)you need to use tricks in order to allow data conversion between client/server. For example, [using strings](http://www.flexpasta.com/index.php/2009/06/01/time-travel-the-curious-case-of-java-blazeds-and-flex/) instead of dates in order to prevent timezone difference. Or [using strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400178/flex-null-integer/2403726#2403726) instead of int/double. You can solve some of these issues by writing custom proxies, but I still think that it's easier to use strings instead of other data types.

c)most of the time you don't need all the data from the domain objects, and in order to deal with that you need to use various frameworks with support for data pagination/lazy instantiation on the client. This frameworks are introducing complexity, and I try to stay away from that.

The main disadvantage of using DTO is the amount of boiler code in order to do the conversion between the domain objects-DTOs...but I still prefer using them.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience, Cornel. Problem "C" that you mention is the one I directly understand, "A" and "B" may hit me later :). One way to deal with "C" I guess would be to accept that you retrieve a lot of extra data in the invocations, but as long as this doesnt cause a performance problem maybe you can live with it? However, if I would go with alternative 3, do you know any good (extensive) example showing how to go from **<flex client domain object>** to **<Java/flex remote service DTO>** to **<Java domain object (annotated with JPA)>**? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. On "C" it depends, sometimes it is acceptable sometimes not. In my experience it wasn't. I do not know about any example unfortunately, maybe I'll add one in future on my blog.